# Como crear un seleccionador de fechas por rango de semanas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Espero que se encuentren muy bien.

La verdad no se si sea el espacio correcto para consultar lo siguiente requiero de tener un seleccionador de fechas por semana es decir que tenga un boton anterior y uno de siguiente para ir seleccionando por un rango de 6 dias, he revisado moment js , day js pero veo que solo puedo obtener los dias del mes, otra opcion que he buscado es obtener todos los dias que muestra el calendario por mes incluyendo los dias de los meses anteriores o siguientes para poder armar los rangos pero no he encontrado informacion , no se si exista algun plugin que ayude a realizar eso o de que manera puedo hacerlo puesto que estoy trabajando con js y php.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el siguiente codigo ya obtengo los 42 dias que muestra el calendario por mes voy a crear los arreglos ahora me faltaria como agregarlo a ese pequeño slider que tiene el boton de next y previous

```
var firstDayOfMonth,firstDayOfCal;
function getDaysForCalendarMonth(date) {
    
      firstDayOfMonth = moment(date).startOf('month');
      firstDayOfCal = firstDayOfMonth.clone().startOf('week');
    var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.clone().endOf('month');
    var lastDayOfCal = lastDayOfMonth.clone().endOf('week');


    var temp = firstDayOfCal.clone();
    var days = [temp.toDate()];
    while (temp.isBefore(lastDayOfCal) && days.length <= 43) {
      temp.add(1, 'day');
      days.push(moment(temp).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
    }
    while (days.length <= 43) {
      temp.add(1, 'day');
      days.push(moment(temp).format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm'));
    }
    
 
    
   //var fecha =  moment(days,'yyyy/MM/DD hh:mm A');
   
    return  days  
  }
  //console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(new Date(2020, 2, 1)));
 // console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(new Date(2020, 3, 1)));
 //var today = new Date();


 var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 //console.log(today);
  console.log(getDaysForCalendarMonth(today));
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?... edita tu pregunta y agrega tu intento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considero que la clase [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) tiene lo necesario para hacer lo que buscas.

Te dejo una implementación completa, aunque rudimentaria en el *look and feel*, considero que tiene lo necesario para que armes tu propia solución.

El snippet a continuación siempre parte de la *semana actual*, que se muestra en un `span` y los botones te permiten navegar hacia las semanas anterior y siguiente de la semana que se muestra.

La *fecha inicial* de la semana está almacenada en la variable `inicioSemana`.

Considero que las funciones se auto-explican, por lo que no hace falta añadir mayores comentarios.

```js
function getInicioSemana() {
  var result = new Date(new Date().toDateString());
  while (result.getDay() != 0) {
    result.setDate(result.getDate() - 1);
  }
  return(result);
}  

function getSemanaSiguiente(inicio) {
  var result = new Date(inicio);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + 7);
  return(result);
}

function getSemanaAnterior(inicio) {
  var result = new Date(inicio);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() - 7);
  return(result);
}

function getDescripcionSemana(inicio) {
  var final = new Date(inicio);
  final.setDate(final.getDate() + 6);

  var result = ""       + inicio.getDate() 
                  + "/" + (inicio.getMonth() + 1)
                  + "/" + inicio.getFullYear()
          + " - " +       final.getDate() 
                  + "/" + (final.getMonth() + 1)
                  + "/" + final.getFullYear()
                  ;
      
  return(result);
}

function actualizarSpanSemana(inicio) {
  document.getElementById("semana").innerHTML = getDescripcionSemana(inicio);
}

function iniSpanSemana() {
  actualizarSpanSemana(inicioSemana);
}

function clicAnterior() {
  inicioSemana = getSemanaAnterior(inicioSemana);
  actualizarSpanSemana(inicioSemana);
}

function clicSiguiente() {
  inicioSemana = getSemanaSiguiente(inicioSemana);
  actualizarSpanSemana(inicioSemana);
}

var inicioSemana = getInicioSemana();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  iniSpanSemana();
});
```

```html
<button onClick="clicAnterior()">&lt;</button>
<span id="semana">0/0/0 - 0/0/0</span>
<button onClick="clicSiguiente()">&gt;</button>
```

He dejado mi ejemplo en un *snippet*, de manera que puedes probarlo directamente aquí en la respuesta haciendo clic en el botón *"ejecutar"*.

Answer (score 1):

Usando la librería de moment.js podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="week-selector">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left previous-week-btn"></i>
        <input type="text" id="start-date" readonly>-<input type="text" id="end-date" readonly>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right next-week-btn"></i>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let startDate = moment().startOf('week');
        let endDate = moment(startDate).add(6, 'days');
        const startDateInput = document.getElementById('start-date');
        const endDateInput = document.getElementById('end-date');
        const previousWeekBtn = document.querySelector('.previous-week-btn');
        const nextWeekBtn = document.querySelector('.next-week-btn');

        const updateDateInputs = () => {
            startDateInput.value = moment(startDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            endDateInput.value = moment(endDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        };
        previousWeekBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            startDate = moment(startDate).subtract(7, 'days').startOf('week');
            endDate = moment(startDate).add(6, 'days');
            updateDateInputs();
        });
        nextWeekBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            startDate = moment(startDate).add(7, 'days').startOf('week');
            endDate = moment(startDate).add(6, 'days');
            updateDateInputs();
        });
        updateDateInputs();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Actualización (explicación del código):

Primero se inicializan dos variables de fecha: startDate y endDate. startDate se establece en el comienzo de la semana actual, y endDate se establece en 7 días después de startDate, lo que significa que endDate representa el final de la semana actual.

Después se obtienen los input fecha inicio y fin a través de su ID y se los almacena en las constantes startDateInput y endDateInput. También se obtienen los botones de flecha a través de su clase y se almacenan en las constantes previousWeekBtn y nextWeekBtn.

Posterior a ello se define una función llamada updateDateInputs que actualiza los valores de las entradas de fecha con las fechas actualizadas. Luego, se llama a esta función para inicializar los campos de entrada con los valores de fecha iniciales.

Después se agregan manejadores de eventos para los botones de flecha. Cuando se hace clic en el botón anterior, se resta una semana de startDate, se recalcula endDate, y luego se llama a la función updateDateInputs para actualizar los campos de entrada. Y cuando se hace clic en el botón siguiente, se agrega una semana a startDate, se recalcula endDate y se llama otra vez a la función updateDateInputs para actualizar los campos de entrada.